# Setting up sliding window for msts() object in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a multiple seasonality time series object for 4 years' worth of daily observations.

```
    y.msts <- msts(full.df$y, seasonal.periods=c(7,365.25))
```

I am trying to create a sliding window for temporal cross-validation using the code below:

```
    train <- window(y.msts,start = (as.Date(as.character("2014- 
    01-01"))),end=(as.Date(as.character("2015-12-31")))) #2014 and 2015 as training set
```

However, I keep getting the following Warning message immediately followed by an Error message ***'end' value not changed Error in window.default(x, ...) : 'start' cannot be after 'end'***

Would someone be able to help me understand why this is happening and what I can do to correct it?